# domdocument how to get info and imgs

Tags: php, html, dom, document

```
<?php 
$htmlget = new DOMDocument();

@$htmlget->loadHtmlFile(http://www.amazon.com);

$xpath = new DOMXPath( $htmlget);
$nodelist = $xpath->query( "//img/@src" );

foreach ($nodelist as $images){
    $value = $images->nodeValue;
}
?>
```

i got all images but how do i get the information around the same element the image is in?  for example, on amazon.com, theres a the kindle. i have the picture now but need the information around such as the price description... 
thanks

Comment: If you especially mean the large kindle-image, there will be no way, because the price you see there is a part of the image and not available inside the DOM. http://g-ecx.images-amazon.com/images/G/01/kindle/merch/shasta-de-redirect-475x313._V182303681_.png

Comment: so, skip this and go through all other images including this one.. then i would be able to sift those that dont have any info int he same element.

Comment: Why are you screenscraping the site instead of using the Amazon API?

Comment: amazon is a example site.. i will scraping others... so i just want to know how to get all information around the images..

Comment: well, we cannot write any code for imaginary sites. If you want so scrape use the API. If you want to scrape another site and run into issues update your question to ask about that particular site. If you are just looking for examples on how to use DOM, browse the available ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the markup of the requested page, here an example for getting the price on amazon:

```
<?php
       $htmlget = new DOMDocument();

       @$htmlget->loadHtmlFile('http://www.amazon.com');

       $xpath = new DOMXPath( $htmlget);
       $nodelist = $xpath->query( "//img/@src" );

        foreach ($nodelist as $imageSrc){

      //fetch images with a parent node that has class "imagecontainer"
      if($imageSrc->parentNode->parentNode->getAttribute('class')=='imageContainer')
      {
        //skip dummy-images
        if(strstr($imageSrc->nodeValue,'transparent-pixel'))continue;

        //point to the common anchestor of image and product-details
        $wrapper=$imageSrc->parentNode->parentNode->parentNode->parentNode->parentNode;

        //fetch the price
        $price=$xpath->query( 'span[@class="red t14"]',$wrapper );
        if($price->length )
        {
           echo '<br/><img src="'.$imageSrc->nodeValue.'">'.$price->item(0)->nodeValue.'<br/>';
        };
      }
}
?>
```

But however, you shouldn't parse  pages that way. If they want to provide you some information, the ususally have an API. If not, they don't want you to grab anything. Parsing that way is not reliable, the markup of the requested page can change every second(you may open a door for exploits too). It also may not be legal .

Comment: THANKs. but amazon was an example..  i want it to be able to be scrapping any site and retrieve back the images first then the any data in the element the image is in..   could be a div containing the image. price. description etc.

Comment: So you have to use `DOMDocument::crystalBall($htmlget,guessWhatIWant)`

Comment: haha..  basically, i want to scrape any url, get the images and somehow get any information contained in its own element.. it could be a div . e.g.  <div id="maindiv"> <img src=''>  <div>blah blah</div> </div>

Comment: There is no "somehow" in PHP or DOM . As long as there is no standard that an image has to own a wrapper which contains further informations, you'll not be able to do it a unique way for any url.

Comment: but if there is no  own wrapper it should display, if it does then display anything in the wrapper.. i dotn mind.  once i have this, i will do the rest i need to the info i get in the wrapper

Comment: define "wrapper" and "info" that it matches for every page you may try to parse!

Comment: any html tag in the parentnode that the image is in.   if it doesnt have one, then it will just load the image.  so basically, i am trying to get all images and get all data from the parent node of the image tag. with regardless if there is one or not.

Comment: This will not work e.g. on amazon.com, because the description & price is not inside the parentNode of the image.

Comment: so theres no way of getting any of the data around the image ?

Comment: There is no unique way for different webpages, that's what me and the comments try to say and you ignore so far.